# Smooth radial collision

Tags: c++, collision-resolution, qt, bounding-spheres

I'm trying to make collisions smoother in my game. Currently, entities will stop completely when they collide with an obstacle. I saw the following article recently:

http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/simple-but-effective-collisions-part-1-radial-collision-handling-r3147

I gave it a try by writing a quick, small example. The commented out code in the function below is my attempt at getting it to work:

```
QPointF handleRadialCollisions() {
        QPointF deltaPos(0, 0);
        foreach (const QGraphicsItem *obstacle, mPlayer->scene()->collidingItems(mPlayer)) {
            const QPointF targetCentrePos = mPlayer->sceneBoundingRect().center();
            const QRectF playerBoundingRect = mPlayer->boundingRect();
            const qreal playerRadius = qMax(playerBoundingRect.width(), playerBoundingRect.height());
            const QRectF obstacleBoundingRect = obstacle->boundingRect();
            const QPointF obstacleCentrePos = obstacle->sceneBoundingRect().center();
            const qreal obstacleRadius = qMax(obstacleBoundingRect.width(), obstacleBoundingRect.height());
            const QPointF vectorToCentre(targetCentrePos.x() - obstacleCentrePos.x(), targetCentrePos.y() - obstacleCentrePos.y());
            if (vectorToCentre.manhattanLength() < obstacleRadius) {
                deltaPos += ((obstacleRadius / vectorToCentre.manhattanLength()) - 1) * vectorToCentre;
            }
//            if (vectorToCentre.manhattanLength() < obstacleRadius + playerRadius) {
//                deltaPos += (((obstacleRadius + playerRadius) / vectorToCentre.manhattanLength()) - 1) * vectorToCentre;
//            }
        }
        return deltaPos;
    }
```

It is used like so:

```
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event) {
        // ... adjust velocity here depending on keys pressed.

        mPlayer->setVelocity(QPointF(xVelocity, yVelocity));

        mPlayer->setPos(mPlayer->pos() + mPlayer->velocity() + handleRadialCollisions());
    }
```

As mentioned in the comments of the article, the method presented doesn't account for the radius of the player. I attempted to fix this (commented out if statement in handleRadialCollisions()), but the player "bounces" off the obstacle instead of smoothly sliding off it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `handleRadialCollisions` the important part?  If so, your answer would be much more readable without all the other code.

Comment: You mean my question? Yes, I mentioned that the commented out code is the problem. There's not that much code, and it allows anyone attempting to answer to actually run something to see the results, which I think is much better than just a snippet.

Comment: Quite right; I meant question.  Too late to edit it.  Seeing the result would be good, but a gif would also accomplish that.  Here are the reasons you might want edit it down.  1. It would take a lot of time to compile and run your code, and you limit potential answerers by demanding extra effort from folks.  2. Seeing the symptoms of your bad implementation doesn't help solve your problem.  That requires editing the relevant code, which is hidden among the non-relevant.  3. On this SE site, we close questions that don't limit their code to tightly isolate the problem.  Still, your choice.

Comment: More on #3: there are now two close votes against your question for not narrowing your code.  Mine was the second.

Comment: I'm just surprised.. if someone's having a problem with something, I find a running example perfect, because I can edit it and see the changes, whereas a few separate snippets leaves me with very little most of the time. Even with the edit saying "the problem is in X function", the previous revision was still considered too much code? I don't think 160 lines of code would be a problem on SO, but like you said, that's how it goes over here.

Comment: Your post probably didn't contain too much code, but it just didn't focus on the important code.  The issue is that most people won't compile and meticulous modify your complete program in order to help you.  That's just too much time to expect from the internet.  Your best chance for good answers is to give something concise that can be quickly read-through and analyzed.  Narrowing down your code is supposed to make your question more likely to succeed, and I think it has.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand this, instead of just downvoting and moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `playerRadius` is twice as big as it should be.  Your `vectorToCentre` is measured from `targetCentrePos`, but you use the full `width()` or `height()` of `playerBoundingRect` to determine radius.

I suggest this change:

```
const qreal playerRadius = qMax(
  playerBoundingRect.width() / 2, 
  playerBoundingRect.height() / 2);
```

Comment: Ah, what a silly mistake. Thanks. I notice that the player still bobs/bounces around the obstacle; do you know why this might happen, and if there's a way to reduce or prevent it?

Comment: There could be a lot of missing subtleties.  The math I mentioned in my answer probably is less than ideal.  It returns the same number each frame, but if the smaller dimension is the colliding side, it's not correct.  It could also be a mismatch between the rectangle size and sprite size, or misplacement of the center, or any number of other things.  You might try to draw the vectors and edges on screen, in order to debug visually.  Good luck.